# PHP session_start, Displaying Japanese characters using 'UTF-8 without BOM' without messing up headers

Tags: php, utf-8, notepad++

Alright, so I'm using Notepad++ to write up a webpage that contains both English and Japanese characters. The website also uses PHP sessions.

After wracking my brain for a while wondering why I was getting this error:

```
'Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent'
```

I realized that because I was using 'Encode in UTF-8', the invisible BOM output was screwing up my PHP headers.

So I switched to 'Encode in UTF-8 without BOM' in Notepad++. Now my PHP sessions work and it doesn't complain about headers, but now Japanese characters don't properly display on the website (although they appear just fine in Notepad++). I traded one problem for another.

How can I get Japanese characters to properly display on my website while still avoiding the UTF-8 encoding issue of sending output before PHP session_start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `addDefaultCharset UTF-8` to `.htaccess` file in the root of your application